# MySQL/Ms SQL latest records with multiple id's

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm no sql-expert, but came across this problem:

I have to retrieve data from Microsoft SQL 2008 server. It holds different measurement data from different probes, that don't have any recording intervals. Meaning that some probe can transfer data in the database once every week, another once every second. Probes are identified by id's (not unique), and the point is to retrieve only the last record from each id (probe). Table looks like this (last 5, order by SampleDateTime desc):

```
TagID   SampleDateTime  SampleValue     QualityID
13      634720670797944946      112     192
23      634720670797944946      38.1    192
17      634720670797944946      107.5   192
14      634720670748012090      110.6   192
19      634720670748012090      99.7    192
```

I CAN'T modify the server or even the settings, am only authorized to do queries. And I'd need to retrieve the requested data on even intervals (say once every minute or so). There are over 100 probes (with different id's) of which about 40 need to be read. So I am guessing that if this could be done in a single query it could be way more efficient than to get each row in a separate query.

Using MySQL and a similar table got the desired result this way (suggestions for a better way highly appreciated!):

```
SELECT TagID,SampleDateTime,SampleValue FROM 
(
    SELECT TagID,SampleDateTime,SampleValue FROM measurements 
    WHERE TagID IN(101,102,103) ORDER BY SampleDateTime DESC
) 
AS table1 GROUP BY TagID;
```

Thought that would do the trick (didn't manage with MAX() or DISTINCT or no matter what I tried), as it did, with the correct data even. But naturally it doesn't work in Ms SQL because of 'GROUP BY'.

```
Column 'table1.SampleValue' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I'm extremely stuck with this and so any insight would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am slightly confused as you have tagged MySQL and SQL-Server. For SQL-Server, I would use the `ROW_NUMBER` function to assist:

```
SELECT  m.TagID, m.SampleDateTime, m.SampleValue, m.QualityID
FROM    (   SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TagID ORDER BY SampleDateTime DESC) [RowNumber]
            FROM    Measurements 
        ) m
WHERE   Rownumber = 1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER` function does exactly what it says on the tin, gives each row a number based on criteria you provide. So in the example above `PARTITION BY TagID` tells `ROW_NUMBER` to start again at 1 each time a new TagID is encountered. `ORDER BY SampleDateTime DESC` tells `ROW_NUMBER` to start numbering the each TagID at the latest entry and work upwards to the earliest entry.

The reason your query failed is because MySQL allows implicit group by, meaning that because you have only specified `GROUP BY TagID` any fields that are in the select list and not contained within an aggregate function will get the values of a "random" row assigned to them (the latest row in your case because you specified `ORDER BY SampleDateTime DESC` in the subquery.

Just in case it is required the following should work in most DBMS and is a better way of producing a similar query to the one you have been running in MySQL:

```
SELECT  m.TagID, m.SampleDateTime, m.SampleValue, m.QualityID
FROM    Measurements m
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  TagID, MAX(SampleDateTime) AS SampleDateTime
            FROM    Measurements
            GROUP BY TagID
        ) MaxTag
            ON MaxTag.TagID = m.TagID
            AND MaxTag.SampleDateTime = m.SampleDateTime
```

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad. Thought first I'd do mysql-->mssql-type of post but then it turned to that. BUT, I can't thank you enough! Will learn to use that first one (gives "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BY'"), but the second one works perfectly so I suppose so will the first one too once I've figured it out. Spent 3 days with that "simple" issue so truly, from the bottom of my heart, THANK YOU!

Comment: Sorry, I missed out `OVER` from the top query. It should work now.